# How to use ask-sdk-v1adapter for migrating a sdk1 lambda code to sdk2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to learn how to migrate a SDK1 code to SDK2, using the ask-sdk-v1adapter , i am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'locale' of undefined or module initialization error: TypeError. I have used a simple Hello world program but still no success. Any help will be much appreciated

I have already installed the required dependencies . The referred site is https://ask-sdk-for-nodejs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ASK-SDK-Migration-Guide.html

```
'use strict';
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-v1adapter');

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
  alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
  alexa.registerV2Handlers(HelloWorldIntentHandler);
  alexa.execute();
};



const handlers = {
  'LaunchRequest': function () {
    this.emit('SayHello');
  },
    'SayHello': function () {
    this.response.speak('Hello World!');
    this.emit(':responseReady');
  },
  'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function () {
    this.response.speak('Goodbye!');
    this.emit(':responseReady');
  },
  'AMAZON.StopIntent': function () {
    this.response.speak('See you later!');
    this.emit(':responseReady');
  }
};

const HelloWorldIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'HelloWorldIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput){
    const speechOutput = 'Hello, welcome to the test.I am working ';

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechOutput)
      .reprompt()
      .getResponse();
  },
};
```

Comment: Just an aside, that documentation doesn't go into specifics about a lot of the methods. Like the Dialog.Directive methods, they mention them (almost not noticeably) once in the section about building a response, but you must reference the documentation on AWS to actually see everything you can do with them.

Comment: Your reprompt is empty. Don't know if that's related to that specific error, but try adding a string in there.

Comment: @dillon.harless, thanks for the reply, but tried with reprompt too..didnt work out

Comment: Hmmm. Is there more to the error?

Comment: In alexa dev console I am getting the error the object provided is not a valid template, when ever I try to invoke the handler written in sdk2 format, any ideas why?

Comment: Can you post the JSON object generated from the alexa console and any errors you get in the Lambda console when testing?

Comment: I am not getting any JSON response when trying to invoke the intent, HelloWorldIntent, just an alert error saying the object provided is not a valid template .

Comment: What about when you test it in Lambda? The Lambda console often presents errors in a much more readable and helpful manner.

Comment: Lambda shows no error and even in cloud watch, cant see any error

Comment: Hmm... okay so let's try two things. Can you post the JSON structure of your skill? You can find it in the JSON editor in the Alexa console. Also can you confirm that your endpoint is set correctly?